# How to serve media content that is being requested through a 404 page in nginx?

Tags: php, nginx, video, media

I am running a nginx server that has basically one empty "image" directory and a 404.php script.

Everytime a user requests an image from the nginx server, e.g. "www.example.com/image/12312.png", the nginx server downloads the image from s3, stores it under that specific name, **and serves it**. Then, the next time the same image is requested, it does no longer need to be downloaded as it is already on the server (and thus the 404 script is no longer triggered, meaning it directly serves the image).

---

I hope you understand the basic picture. It's essentially mirroring media content and **serving it right away**. Now, the **bold part** is currently what I cannot figure out how to solve - everything else except that part works perfectly!

I assume this is because the nginx server sends a 404 reply along the picture, which makes it not display the picture. I have to make the visitor reload the page the first time a file is requested, which is troublesome.

Do you have any idea how I can solve this?

---

Here's my current code for displaying the image (or, video in this case) in pseudocode:

**404.php**

```
// Get requested file
$requestedFile = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$localFile = $requestedFile
$remoteFile = "s3.example.com/".$requestedFile

// Download and store file from s3
file_put_contents($remoteFile, $localFile);

// Serve the stored file
// THIS PART IS WHERE I ENCOUNTER PROBLEMS - THE VIDEO IS NOT BEING DISPLAYED!
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length:'.filesize($localFile));
readfile($localFile);
```

Hope you understand what I am trying to do and what exactly the issue is. Otherwise I can give you more information.

Comment: The server probably already set the HTTP status to 404 at this point. Maybe you can change it back to 200 with `header` or `http_response_code`?

Comment: @KarstenKoop I'm not sure but I think I tried exactly this, and I think nginx overrode the header again.

Comment: What is your nginx config?

Comment: Hi @ShawnC, here are my nginx configs. Default config: https://pastebin.com/raw/CiPEcBNz Domain config: https://pastebin.com/raw/argKJAwQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your configs I would try:

Removing

```
error_page 404 /404.php;
```

and adding something like

```
location / {
        try_files $uri /404.php?$args =404;
}
```

The `error_page` per the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) always returns that error code (can force the status code) but always returns a hardcoded status code. `try_files` will look for the file then if not found go to your `404.php` then if that doesn't work will then return a true `404`.

Comment: I understand your approach and I think that's exactly the way to go. Unfortunately, upon following your instructions, I only get a 404 page when using it on videos that haven't been saved yet. Any ideas on why that could be?

Comment: Update! When I remove the " =404" part it works perfectly. Looks like the server's nginx version is <0.7.51, so it does not support that. Thanks :-)